# NSURLConnection Stop Vibrating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

So I have been using NSURLConnection to handle talking to a google app engine server I have running for my app.

Whenever I make a request (actually I think its on getting a response), the phone will vibrate.
Is there any way to prevent this from happening? Users of my app already know when they get new data and so don't need the phone to vibrate, and it gets annoying when it happens a couple of times over a few seconds.

On a side note, is it bad practice to send more than a few requests in a given minute?

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection doesn't make the phone vibrate. It's probably something in other parts of your code. Try to search for this line:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

About the network request every few seconds, it should't be a problem, but use a flag to have only one alive request at a time (if the previous request take so much time)